# How do I uninstall Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to uninstall Visual studio 2008 from my system, but I do not see Visual studio 2008 in the list on the "Uninstall or change a program" dialog box in windows 7.  I also checked the Visual Studio 2008 folder in the Programs folder, but I could not find anything to start the uninstallation wizard. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Visual Studio 2008 Uninstall Tool that might help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joy/archive/2009/10/16/microsoft-visual-studio-2008-rc-rtm-uninstall-tool.aspx